# FTP Async causes the file to be zero bytes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, ftp

I am trying to using async await  to upload a file (The file is passed through as a byte array). I have a synchronous version which is working ok but the async version creates a file on the FTP server but is zero bytes.

Sync version

```
public virtual void UploadFile(IFile file)
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someFtpsite.com");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = Credentials;
    request.ContentLength = file.FileContents.Length;

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(file.FileContents, 0, file.FileContents.Length);
    }
}
```

Async

```
public virtual async Task UploadFileAsync(IKCFile file)
{
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someFtpsite.com");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = Credentials;
    request.ContentLength = file.FileContents.Length;

    using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        await requestStream.WriteAsync(file.FileContents, 0, file.FileContents.Length);
        await requestStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add following to the request : request.UseBinary = true;

Comment: @jdweng That's the default value – and even if it were not, if the synchronous code works, why would it make a difference with the asynchronous?

Comment: @Rhodes73 I've tested your code with `byte[]` buffer  instead of `file.FileContents` and it works correctly for me => We need [mcve]. + Btw, why don't you simply use [`WebClient.UploadDataAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync) or [`WebClient.UploadDataTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddatataskasync)?

Answer (score -1):

The methods were being called synchronously which was causing the issue